# sir Google play is showing unwanted apps to install and unwanted information about something repeatedly.can u help me to avoid that disturbance

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

[image]
Like I attached a pic it is showing repeatedly

Comment: Please  describe how this occur? Simply shows popup or while browsing using chrome/ firefox / any other browser?

Comment: It's probably an ad sent to you by one of the apps you downloaded

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't understand your question fully, but as far as i understand you get notifications to install this app ?
If so then long click on the notification to see which app displays it (i had Go Keyboard annoying me with ads) and uninstall this app or block notifications. If not, then run a malware scan for your device using any antivirus from Google play.